# What is the exact list of parameters and their description for jspdf's addImage() function?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I can see in the console that `addImage()` function of jspdf library has [9 parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTEor.png). I've seen people using first 5 of them, but not completely sure even about them. Unfortunately, documentation for this method is not provided on [official web-site](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html). Also, corresponding github issues are closed.

Comment: [`.addImage()`](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/docs/plugins_addimage.js.html#L559): `jsPDFAPI.addImage = function(imageData, format, x, y, w, h, alias, compression, rotation) {`

Comment: @Andreas, thank you, that's exactly what i needed. Why comment, not answer?

Comment: I've added some more information to the comment and added it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [source](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/docs/plugins_addimage.js.html#L559) you can find the method signature as follows:

```
function(imageData, format, x, y, w, h[, alias[, compression[, rotation]]])
```

---

`imageData` has to be:

- an [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object
- an `<img>` element
- a `<canvas>` element
- an image as a [`data uri`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)
- or an object with at least an `imageData` property (with one of the above data types)
  In this case the object can then also define the values of the other parameters as properties of the object.

`format` has to be:

- one of the following strings (case insensitive): `'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'`
- If the type is not `string` then the script acts like the function has the following signature (`format` is now the sixth parameter):

  ```
  function(imageData, x, y, w, h[, format[, alias[, compression[, rotation]]]])
  ```

  where `format` would have a default value of `jpeg`

`x` and `y` have to be:

- numbers which define the upper left corner of the image in the PDF ([in millimeters](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/90)!)

`w` and `h` have to be:

- numbers which define the width and height of the image (also in millimeters)

`alias` (optional) has to be:

- a unique string to identify the image (used for the internal cache)
- or `undefined` or `null`
  In this case the unique identifier is a hash of the image

`compression` (optional) has to be:

- one of the following strings (case insensitive): 'NONE', 'FAST', 'MEDIUM', 'SLOW'
  Any other type or value will set the `compression` to `NONE`

`rotation` (optional, only relevant when `imageData` is a DOM element) has to be:

- a number defining the rotation in degrees
- or an object which can then define:

  - the angle of rotation (`angle`)
  - the center of rotation (`x` and `y`) (optional, default: center of the canvas)
  - the background color (`bg`) (optional, default: `'white'`)

---

The answer is based on the code available [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/docs/plugins_addimage.js.html#L559).
If there are any errors or missing information feel free to add them :)